# Java WS get SOAP request CDATA body

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws, cdata

I need to get the following SOAP request into my controller.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<req:ResultMsg
xmlns:req="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/result"><![CDATA[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
<ResultType>0</ResultType>
<ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
<ResultDesc>The service request is processed successfully.</ResultDesc>
<OriginatorConversationID>S_X2013012921001</OriginatorConversationID>
<ConversationID>AG_20130129T102103</ConversationID>
<TranactionID>XD2013012923789234</TranactionID>
<ResultParameters></ResultParameters>
</Result>]]></req:ResultMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to set a POJO and a string for the CDATA part but not working.
Current implementation as below,

Interface:

```
@WebService(name = "VCashCallbackService",
    targetNamespace = "http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/result")
public interface VCashCallbackService {
@WebMethod(operationName = "ResultMsg")
@WebResult(name = "GetDataResponse")
GetDataResponse getData(@WebParam(name = "ResultMsg",
        targetNamespace = "http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/resul",
        mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) Holder<String> searchResultDataXML);

}
```

Impl

```
@WebService(serviceName = "VCashCallbackService",
    portName = "VCashCallbackServicePort",
    endpointInterface = "com.argon.eightd.web.restful.mock.VCashCallbackService",
    targetNamespace = "http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/result")
@BindingType(value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@Service
public class VCashCallbackServiceImpl implements VCashCallbackService {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VCashCallbackServiceImpl.class);

@Override
public GetDataResponse getData(Holder<String> searchResultDataXML) {
    LOGGER.info("SOAP result: {}", searchResultDataXML.searchResultDataXML.value);
    return new GetDataResponse();
}
```

}

Log

```
SOAP result: null
```

But this approach is getting the request as above in the WebMethod.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please post code as code (text with code tags around it) instead of images. Those images are compressed and thus (some of them) unreadable. Also registering it as an `@Service` won't automatically make the `!WebService` work, you will need to export it as a jax-ws service using the `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter` (actually that will automatically detect the beans and export them).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @M.Deinum, I have updated the question. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: I already gave the answer in the comment. Add a `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter` as a bean to export the service or use something like ApacheCXF with proper Spring integration setup to export the service. Also the `toString` is of the `Holder` not the `String`. Why do you want to string and not the actual request object? Why parse it yourself, that basically defeats the purpose of using Jax-ws in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter approach. I want to get it as String because the body is not a default XML, it is a CDATA. (Updated the XML part of the question)